# Append NSStrings and NSNumber to NSMutableArrays and make NSMutable dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm getting data from SQL server in following variables in one class:

```
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSString* trainingName;
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSNumber* trainingCount;
```

In other class,I want to append this value in NSMutableArray and finally make a dictonary.I'm doing this as following:

```
-(void)getTrainingDetails
{
MyTestSp_GetTrainingCountsList *objReturnTrainings = [MyTestSp_GetTrainingCounts findAll];
NSMutableArray *trainingNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *trainingCounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *dictTrainings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

if ([objReturnTrainings length] > 0)
{
    for (MyTestSp_GetTrainingCounts *obj in objReturnTrainings)
    {
        // get the values and assign to NSMutable array
        trainingNames = trainingName;
        trainingCounts = trainingCount;
        //Make the dictionary.
    }

}
```

}

Is this the correct way of doing and how can I put this in dictionary?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to set your array directly to your number / string (which you aren't actually getting out of `obj` so your code shouldn't compile...). You also don't need the arrays to create the dictionary. You can just do:

```
for (MyTestSp_GetTrainingCounts *obj in objReturnTrainings)
{
    dictTrainings[obj.trainingName] = obj.trainingCount;
}
```